# pandas dataframe column contains string and int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, typeerror

My data-frame age column looks like this

20 or younger =14

61 or older   =45

56-60         = 34

31-35        =30

56 or older  =31

21-25     =23

26  30    =56

31  35  =44

36  40  =32

21  25  =26

26-30 =14

46  50  =14

36-40 =15

46-50  =33

41  45  =24

41-45  =29

51-55 =35

so i wrote this function to categorize it better but i got this typeerror message that says '<' not supported between instance of str and int

def age_buckets(x):

```
if x < 30: 
    return '18-29' 
elif x < 40: 
    return '30-39' 
elif x < 50: 
    return '40-49' 
elif x < 60: 
    return '50-59' 
elif x < 70: 
    return '60-69' 
elif x >=70: 
    return '70+' 
else: return 'other'
```

Here is a link to what i am doing
https://deepnote.com/workspace/eddie-abfa350f-f15e-43fe-8960-fab53a2def2e/project/Welcome-e6ac66b9-19f2-4973-bbc2-7adfda9366f3/%2FReasons%20for%20resignation%20analysis.ipynb

Comment: do you want to add a print screen with your data frame and the error message?

Comment: i am not allowed to embed image in my post yet

Comment: i will work on that straight up, i'm new posting questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare a string of characters with the `<` check. It doesn't associate that string with a number. That error says that the incoming `x` value is a `string`. Therefore, in order to do this, `x` must be a number. If it is in-fact an `int`, you can cast it with the `int()` function.
Such as `int(x) < 30`...

What would be better is that you pass `age_buckets` an `int` rather than a `string`. So when you call it just do `age_buckets(int(x))` rather than just `age_buckets(x)`

Please see :
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

So when you do  `combined['age'] = combined['age'].apply(age_buckets(int(x)))`
you actually need to do
`combined['age'] = combined['age'].apply(age_buckets,1))`

See if :

```
def age_buckets(y):
     x = int(y)
     if x < 30:
        ...
```

works

Comment: Please add some code and error messages so that people can see what you're working with.

Comment: i tried to call the function this way                                                            combined['age'] = combined['age'].apply(age_buckets(int(x)))   and i encountered a name error:'x' is not defined

Comment: Where is x coming from? And you are trying to do an apply() check on the whole column?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to apply () on the whole column

Comment: you didn't answer where `x` is coming from. If its not defined you aren't setting it. `x` seems to be the index/row number to grab.

Comment: i followed your reply above that i should  "So when you call it just do age_buckets(int(x)) "

Comment: no... `x` is the name of the variable inside of the function `age_buckets`. Whatever the name of the variable that you are passing to `age_buckets` needs to have the `int()` around it. Please post some code.

Comment: i am not allowed to add embed image yet, i'm new here, i have added the print screen description above

Comment: see editied answer above.

Comment: i am so sorry if i have bothered you ...i encountered a 
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: So back to the original issue. I detailed another solution above.

Comment: http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Reasons%20for%20resignation%20analysis.ipynb           This is the link, i encountered a     TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: https://deepnote.com/workspace/eddie-abfa350f-f15e-43fe-8960-fab53a2def2e/project/Welcome-e6ac66b9-19f2-4973-bbc2-7adfda9366f3/%2FReasons%20for%20resignation%20analysis.ipynb